# How to add duplicate columns together after converting from excel to json in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, excel

I have excel file in the format :

| Name | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | Q1 | a1 |
| N2 | Q2 | a2 |
| N3 | Q3 | a3 |
| N4 | Q4 | a4 |
| N3 | Q5 | a3 |

Here some name are same and their correspondings answers are also same. I want to convert this into json in the format where all the columns with same name are merged.

```
{
  {
    "name":"N1",
    "exampleSentences": ["Q1"],
    "defaultReply": {
        "text": ["a1"],
        "type": "text"
    }
  },
  {
    "name":"N2",
    "exampleSentences": ["Q2"],
    "defaultReply": {
        "text": ["a2"],
        "type": "text"
    }
  },
  {
    "name":"N3",
    "exampleSentences": ["Q3","Q5"],
    "defaultReply": {
        "text": ["a3"],
        "type": "text"
    }
  },
  {
    "name":"N4",
    "exampleSentences": ["Q4"],
    "defaultReply": {
        "text": ["a4"],
        "type": "text"
    }
  },
}
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
# Import the required python modules
import pandas as pd
import math
import json
import csv

# Define the name of the Excel file
fileName = "FAQ_eng"

# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel("{}.xlsx".format(fileName))

intents = []
intentNames = df["Name"]

# Loop through the list of Names and create a new intent for each row
for index, name in enumerate(intentNames):

    if name is not None:
        exampleSentences = []
        defaultReplies = []

        if df["Question"][index] is not None and df["Question"][index] is not float:

            try:
                exampleSentences = df["Question"][index]
                exampleSentences = [exampleSentences]
           
                defaultReplies = df["Answer"][index]
                defaultReplies = [defaultReplies]
                
            except:
                continue
      

        intents.append({
            "name": name,
            "exampleSentences": exampleSentences,
            "defaultReply": {
                "text": defaultReplies,
                "type": "text"
            }
        })

# Write the list of created intents into a JSON file
with open("{}.json".format(fileName), "w", encoding="utf-8") as outputFile:
    json.dump(intents, outputFile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

My code adds another json data

```
  {
    "name":"N3",
    "exampleSentences": ["Q5"],
    "defaultReply": {
        "text": ["a3"],
        "type": "text"
    }
```

instead of merging Q3 and Q5. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is you are iterating through a set of items and at every iteration you should check the previous items to see if your current element is already present. You can avoid this problem if you use an initially empty dictionary `d` storing *key, value* pairs in the form `d[name] = {"exampleSentences": [question], "text": [answer]}`. You can iterate so over `df["Name"]` like below:

```
intentNames = df["Name"]
d = {}

# Loop through intentNames and create the dictionary
for index, name in enumerate(intentNames):
    question = df["Question"][index]
    answer = df["Answer"][index]
    if name not in d:
        d[name] = {"exampleSentences": [question], "text": [answer]}
    else:
        d[name]["exampleSentences"].append(question)
```

Then you can use the created dictionary to create the json file with the expected output like below:

```
intentNames = df["Name"]
d = {}

# Loop through intentNames and create the dictionary
for index, name in enumerate(intentNames):
    question = df["Question"][index]
    answer = df["Answer"][index]
    if name not in d:
        d[name] = {"exampleSentences": [question], "text": [answer]}
    else:
        d[name]["exampleSentences"].append(question)

#create the json array file
intents = []
for k, v in d.items():
    intents.append({
        "name": k,
        "exampleSentences": v['exampleSentences'],
        "defaultReply": {
            "text": v['text'],
            "type": "text"
        }
    })

# Write the list of created intents into a JSON file
with open("{}.json".format(fileName), "w", encoding="utf-8") as outputFile:
    json.dump(intents, outputFile, ensure_ascii=False)
```